# Getting the value from combobox's in Qt for serial connection

Tags: c++, qt, serial-port, qcombobox

I have this problem with Qt whenever I try to set up a connection it never actually takes my data (e.g port name and baud rate) from the combo boxes and apparently it is because I do not link them very well. This is how I did it so far and, well, it doesn't work...

```
void MainWindow::openSerialPort()
{    
    serial.setPortName(ui->portBox->itemData(ui->portBox->currentIndex()));
    printf("%s \n", ui->portBox->itemData(ui->portBox->currentIndex()));
    printf("\n ------------ \n");
    serial.setBaudRate(ui->baudBox->currentIndex());
    printf("%d \n", ui->baudBox->itemData(ui->baudBox->currentIndex()));
//    serial.setDataBits();
...
}
```

Any suggestions?

---

Secondary question: Am I adding the items to the combo box correctly?

```
    ui->baudBox->addItem(QStringLiteral("38400"), QSerialPort::Baud38400);
    ui->baudBox->addItem(QStringLiteral("57600"), QSerialPort::Baud57600);
    ui->baudBox->addItem(QStringLiteral("115200"), QSerialPort::Baud115200);
```

Comment: The printf()'s server mostly for me to test whether it sends the right data. So far it sends gibberish like:
 <empty space, yes an actual empty space>               
 ------------ 
2726128

Comment: Why are you using `baudBox`'s current index to get `itemData` from `portBox`?

Comment: @thuga is correct, there is a mess of names

Comment: You're also setting `baudBox->currentIndex()` as the baud rate. I imagine this is a very small number.

Comment: Does not that get me the item on the selected index?

Comment: No, it gives you the current index. If you have 3 options, it will return a value between 0-2.

Comment: Well, how can I get the string for the port and the QSerialPort::Baud57600 whatever for the baud rate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[QComboBox::currentData()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcombobox.html#currentData-prop) return the QVariant which you provided when adding the currently selected item into the widget. To get the user data from your combobox selection as your serial port baud rate, use

```
serial.setBaudRate(ui->baudBox->currentData().toInt());
```

Comment: I believe I tried this earlier but I had to add within the brackets of itemData() something like:

 QVariant itemData(int index, int role = Qt::UserRole)

And I had no idea what to do so I just ignored it and tried something else.

Comment: Apologies, I meant currentData()

Comment: I suppose you could also use itemData(currentIndex()) ... but that's what currentData is.

Comment: I just tried it and it unexpectedly crashed with the error:

Error - RtlWerpReportException failed with status code :-1073741823. Will try to launch the process directly

Comment: it shouln't. currentIndex() return the index of the selected item, currentData() returns the QVariant you provided when inserting the selected item.

Comment: I am not entirely sure why do we convert to int, while we set the baud rate using QSerialPort::Baud1200?

Comment: You need to convert the QVariant back into the type you originaly provided. Note that QSerialPort::SetBaudRate() takes an Int as argument, the enum type (http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qserialport.html#BaudRate-enum) is also an Int and contains the baudrate value.

Comment: That worked!!! Also can you suggest me a way of getting the port to read it as a QSerialInfo instead of a string?

Comment: I believe SO etiquette is for you to create a separate question ... asking for extra stuff in comments is probably frowned upon.

Comment: Well, I apologize, I did not really think it was that big of a deal to ask something so simple (I guess) here, instead of creating a whole new question. Stackoverflow's etiquette tends to be rather funny most of the time, it seems. Still, thank you for everything!

Comment: no worries, it's not a big deal ... but by asking a full question (not in the comments) you enable other developers to find answers in the future. For your issue, just call QSerialPortInfo::availablePorts() to get a list of ports that you can use to populate your combobox.

Comment: Yep, that was it. I think I got it running. Thank you once again!